# How to denote line segment lengths of a triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wanted to ask how line segment lengths can be denoted in LaTeX. Below are my example codes which draw a triangle. Then, I want to denote the length of line segment OA by $d_1$ and that of OB by $d_2$. Instead of only adding texts below the line segments, I wish to show dimension lines that separate the two lengths. Could someone let me know how it can be done?

Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{0.9}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}[every edge quotes/.append style = {anchor=south, sloped}]
\fill (0,0) circle (2pt);
\draw[->] (0,0) node[below left] (O) {O} -- (8+2.2361,0);
\draw[->] (0,0) to (8,2) node[above] (P) {P};
\draw[->] (8,2) -- (8-2.2361,0) node[below left] (A) {A};  
\draw[->] (8,2) to (8+2.2361,0) node[below right] (B) {B};  

\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered_image]

Comment: See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9006/why-did-a-moderator-delete-an-on-topic-question-with-a-well-received-answer for discussion about this question, which also covers why it is locked

Answer (score 6):

A do not know what you exactly mean by "curves". -but you can use a `dimline` from the `tikz-dimline` package. Like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-dimline}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill (0,0) circle (2pt);

\draw[->] (0,0) node[anchor=north east] (O) {O} -- (12,0) node[anchor=north] (los) {$\hat{l}$};
\draw[->] (0,0) --node[above] {$\vec{d}$} ++ (8,2) node[anchor=south west] (P) {P};
% How can I add an angle symbol at O. 

% Is there an intelligent way of identifying these intersection points?
\draw[->] (8,2) -- (8-2.2361,0) node[anchor=north east] (A) {A};  
\draw[->] (8,2) -- (8+2.2361,0) node[anchor=north west] (B) {B};  

% How can I add curves to indicate the lengths?
\draw (0,0) -- ++ (8-2.2361,0);
  \dimline{(8-2.2361,-1)}{(0,-1)} {$l_{min}$};
\draw (0,0) -- ++ (8+2.2361,0);
  \dimline[extension start length=2 cm] {(8+2.2361,-2)}{(0,-2)} {$l_{max}$};
% The text l_max should be away from the line.  

\draw[dashed] (8,0) -- (8,2);
\draw (8,0.25) -| (7.75,0);
\draw (8,2) circle (3); 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Original figure with dimension lines]